# How to show that $\arctan(x)+\arctan(\frac{1-x}{1+x})$ a given piece-wise function?

Tags: calculus

Show that $$\arctan(x)+\arctan\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)=\begin{cases} \frac\pi4 \quad \;\quad x>-1\\\frac{-3\pi}4\quad\quad x<-1 \end{cases}$$

$$\frac{d(\arctan(\frac{1-x}{1+x}))}{dx}=\frac{1}{1+(\frac{1-x}{1+x})^2}.\frac{-(1+x)-(1-x)}{(x+1)^2}=-\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

so   $\arctan(x)=\arctan(\frac{1-x}{1+x})+c_1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the addition formula for arctangent, namely
$$\arctan u + \arctan v = \arctan\left(\frac{u + v}{1 - uv}\right) \pmod{\pi}$$

provided $uv \ne 1$,
we have that

\begin{align*}
\arctan x + \arctan \left(\frac{1 - x}{1 + x}\right) &= \arctan\left(\frac{x + \frac{1 - x}{1 + x}}{1 - x \frac{1 - x}{1 + x}}\right) \pmod{\pi} \\
&= \arctan\left(\frac{x + x^2 + 1 - x}{1 + x - x(1 - x)}\right) \pmod{\pi} \\
&= \arctan \left(\frac{x^2 + 1}{1 + x^2}\right) \pmod{\pi} \\
&= \frac{\pi}{4} \pmod{\pi}
\end{align*}

Now the result follows by continuity, by evaluating at a random point to the right of $-1$, and a random point left of $-1$.